# vector pushback calling destructor on calling a function

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

I have a structure

```
struct Point
{

    int x,y;
    Point(int _x,int _y)
    {
    x=_x,y=_y;
    }
    int GetX()
    {
    return x;
    }
    int GetY()
    {
    return y;
    }

}
```

in my program if i call

```
Point *ptr=new Point(5,10);
vector<Point>allpts;
allpts.push_back(Point(ptr->GetX(),ptr->GetY());
```

After this line

ptr is getting deleted after push back when it should not.

why is this happening?

Comment: `ptr is getting deleted after push back when it should not.` What?  How do you know?

Comment: Why do you allocate a `Point` dynamically using `new`? Did you ever touch Java?

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in having a constructor that only initializes all data members with copies of parameters in your example. Also the getters are without merit when the data members are public. The only thing that would be of interest to make your claim

> ptr is getting deleted after push back when it should not.

observable, a destructor that tells about the object being destructed, is missing from your example. Code with the same effect:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
    ~Point() { std::cout << "Point dtor called for " << this << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    Point *ptr = new Point{ 5, 10 };
    std::cout << "ptr points to " << ptr << '\n';

    std::vector<Point>allpts;
    allpts.push_back(*ptr);

    // delete ptr;
}
```

Sample output (without `delete ptr;`):

```
ptr points to 0018DE58
Point dtor called for 0018DBF0
```

Sample output (with `delete ptr;`):

```
ptr points to 0018DE58
Point dtor called for 0018DBF0
Point dtor called for 0018DE58
```

As you can see, the Object `ptr` points to does not get deleted unless it is done explicitly.